# Run setter when attribute properties changes

Tags: python-3.6

I would like to use the python setter function (eventually to stick metadata to an object). the method works when the complete attribute changes, but it does not when an attributes' attribute changes:

**MWE**

```
class MyObject():

    def __init__(self, props):
        self.props = props

    @property
    def props(self):
        return self._props

    @props.setter
    def props(self, p):
        print("setter called!")
        self._props = p
```

*1 - Initialize object:*

```
myobject = MyObject(props={"name": "API"})`
```

> setter called!

*2 - Change attribute `props`:*

```
myobject.props = {"name": "anyone else"}
```

> setter called!

*3 - Change attributes' properties:*

```
myobject.props['name'] = "yet anyone else"
```

and this does not run the setter

Answer (score 0):

In third situation it does not work as you think it should.

```
In [1]: class MyObject():
   ...:     def __init__(self, props):
   ...:         self.props = props
   ...:
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def props(self):
   ...:         print("property called!")
   ...:         return self._props
   ...:
   ...:     @props.setter
   ...:     def props(self, p):
   ...:         print("setter called!")
   ...:         self._props = p
   ...:

In [2]: myobject.props['name'] = "yet anyone else"
property called!
```

Setter is called when you try assign new object to **props**. In case which you provided, firstly you get dictionary attached to props via property method and then set new value for one of keys. Setter **will not** work for changing mutable objects inside.

You've probably need to provide your own class for **props** or use [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). If you need more help provide more detailed example.